# How to enable add to cart button for out of stock product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Background: I have a Woocommerce store that is set up such that backorders are allowed for all products. However, despite backorders being allowed, when a product is listed as out of stock, the add to cart button disappears. I've done a bit of research online, and it seems that around July of 2016, Woocommerce changed the backorders feature so that it would no longer allow customers to add products that are listed as out of stock to their cart.

I've heard a bunch of reasons for this change. However, it is important for my business to differentiate between out of stock products and in stock products--mostly to give customers notice that they will not receive out of stock products for 2-3 weeks, but in stock products will be delivered in just 3-4 days.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I might address this problem? I'm pretty weak at coding, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

As woocommerce provide Allow backorders feature so you don't need to do any custom code for this.

Please follow following steps:-
1-Keep your product in-stock.
2-In back-order dropdown select =>Allow, but notify customer option.
3-Check product on frontend.

Now add-to-cart button is enabled for back-orders and back order notification is also showing on the product page.

May this will help you.